# Can I use cross-origin resources within a subdomain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

I would like to know if the following is possible:

Let's say my website = www.mywebsite.com
The code looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...some stuff...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="testDiv"></div>
    <iframe src="//widget.mywebsite.com/widget.php"></iframe>
    ...some stuff...
</body>
</html>
```

The page: //widget.mysite.com/widget.php looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    ...some stuff...
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="someactions.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to access the div with id `testDiv` **from** //widget.mywebsite.com/widget.php

Is this possible when there is another subdomain (so *widget.* instead of *www.*) and another ip for *widget.* and *www.* ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. You just have to ensure that both the parent page and the page in the iframe set the same document.domain

```
document.domain = "mysite.com"
```